# Presence indicator position issue in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, presence-indication

I'm showing presence indicator in SharePoint 2013 page using html code snippet. Its showing on  click & mouse hover of user name, but the position of indicator is not accurate. its showing at bottom of page. I tried to inspect element to adjust css but its not inspecting.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Html:**

```
"<span class=\"ms-imnSpan\">" +
                        "<a class=\"ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink\" aria-hidden=\"true\" onclick=\"IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;\" href=\"#\">" +
                        "<span class=\"ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10\">" +
                        "<img name=\"imnmark\" title=\"\" class=\"ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-offline-10x10x32\" id=\"imn_1,type=sip\" alt=\"Offline\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png\" sip=\"" + emailId + "\" showofflinepawn=\"1\">" +
                        "</span></a></span><span class=\"ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan\"><a tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"ms-imnlink\" aria-hidden=\"true\" onclick=\"IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;\" href=\"#\">" +
                        "<img name=\"imnmark\" title=\"\" class=\" ms-hide\" id=\"imn_2,type=sip\" alt=\"Offline\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png\" sip=\"" + emailId + "\" showofflinepawn=\"1\">" +
                        "</a>\"" + userName + "\"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Can anyone know how to change the position of presence indicator? any help will be appreciated. Thanks.